# emotion with react 18 and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion, react-18

The `css` prop isn't working when I try to use create-react-app with react 18, typescript and emotion 11 — elements are still onstyled, and in the DOM the element has a `css` attribute whose value is:

> You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).

I can reproduce by setting up a new project:

```
npx create-react-app test-ts-emotion --template typescript
cd test-ts-emotion 
npm i --save @emotion/react
```

Then I edit `src/App.tsx` to be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { css } from '@emotion/react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div css={css`background-color: red`}>
      Hello, tester.
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and I add `jsxImportSource` to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Nevertheless, the css prop doesn't work (the element is unstyled and I get the above message as the value for the DOM attribute):

[image: screenshot of error with DOM inspector]

You can check this setup at [my test repo on Github](https://github.com/noahlt/test-ts-emotion).  I believe I've followed [the instructions](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript), but perhaps I'm missing something.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72272133/unable-to-setup-emotion-with-typescript-jsximportsource
this may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, like me, you're using `create-react-app`, you must add an explicit configuration to the top of every file:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
```

This solution is referenced and confirmed in [this Emotion issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2752#issuecomment-1130125642). It's ultimately a `create-react-app` bug. A fix exists in [this pull request on create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10583), but it was submitted over a year ago and nobody at Facebook has bothered to look at it, so I doubt it will ever be merged.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but relevant; ye could keep your tsconfig.json configuration and just add NPM dependency to your project:

```bash
npm i @emotion/babel-preset-css-prop --save-dev
```

finally, add a configuration to your **babel.config.json** as follows:

```json
{ "presets": [ "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop" ] }
```

P.S.
repo to minimal React 18 + TypeScript + Emotion template:- [**github repo**](https://github.com/DAnchor/react18-typescript-and-emotion-template)