# Unable to setup Emotion with typescript jsxImportSource

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, emotion

When looking at the emotion docs, it seams very simple to add it to a react+typescript project.
However, I followed the [Typescript instructions](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript) to add it to a fresh create-react-app project: https://github.com/testerez/cra-ts-emotion/commit/086cc35cda04a1bb72917ccd3a5b79e81e8be1d9

But when I try to use `css` prop in any way:

```
    <div>
  <div css={{ color: "red" }}>Hello!</div>
  <div css={css({ color: "red" })}>Hello!</div>
  <div
    css={css`
      color: red;
    `}
  >
    Hello!
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result I get:

```
<div>
  <div css="[object Object]">Hello!</div>
  <div
    css="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop)."
  >
    Hello!
  </div>
  <div
    css="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop)."
  >
    Hello!
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my test project: https://github.com/testerez/cra-ts-emotion

What did I miss??

Answer (score 6):

You can either add the `jsxImportSource` pragma to every file, or you can specify it once in `tsconfig.json` and once in `vite.config.ts`:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

```
// vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({ jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react' })],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered on this [github issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2752):

> you need to add `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` to the top of every file where you use the css prop.